# How to center Menu Items of Navigation View in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, menuitem, android-navigationview

I am using *Xamarin* (C#) and in my app I have a navigation view with some menu items.

I want to align all of them to the center of the view.

How can I achieve this?

I have already tried with `android:layout_gravity="center"` and `android:gravity="center"` but they both didn't work.

[image: screenshot]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy5a7.png)

main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main_content">
            <EditText
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText1" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/myButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Play" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-65dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-65dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/headerdrawerlayout" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

navmenu.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item_overview"
        android:title="Play"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item_notifications"
        android:title="Notifications"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item_leaderboard"
        android:title="Leaderboard"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item_profile"
        android:title="My Profile"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item_friends"
        android:title="Friends"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item_createQuestion"
        android:title="Create Question"/>

  </group>

  <group android:id="@+id/group_settings_id"
      android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:title="Settings" />
    <item
        android:title="Log Out" />
  </group>


</menu>
```

**Edit**

I have added a ListView to my NavigationView, but I am still not able to center menu items.
Do you have any idea how it could be solved?

Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main_content">
            <EditText
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText1" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/myButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Play" />
            <Button
                android:text="image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button1" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-65dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-65dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <include
                layout="@layout/headerdrawerlayout" />
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);

        // Initialize toolbar
        var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.app_name);

        // Attach item selected handler to navigation view
        var navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
        var navListView = navigationView.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list_menu);
        List<string> listItems = new List<string> { "Play", "Notifications", "Leaderboard", "My Profile", "Friends", "Create Question" };
        ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, listItems);
        navListView.Adapter = adapter;

        //navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected;

        // Create ActionBarDrawerToggle button and add it to the toolbar
        var drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, Resource.String.app_name, Resource.String.app_name);
        drawerLayout.AddDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerToggle.SyncState();

        // Add close button handler to navigation view
        var navigationCloseButton = navigationView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.closeButton);
        navigationCloseButton.Click += delegate
        {
            drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
        };

    }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7QwU.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Can you please show your code of navmenu?

Comment: I have attached my navmenu

Comment: Are you sure this is your navmenu? It's not match the image you posted.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong screenshot. I have uptaded

Comment: Instead of using a menu, You'll need to use `ListView` or `RecyclerView` inside your `NavigationView`. You can then each customise the rows anyway you want as with a normal `ListView` or `RecyclerView`

Comment: And how can i add my menu items to the ListView?

Comment: changed to `ListView` but did not work, Any further idea?